# waitformultipleobjects with unknown number of handles

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

This is what I need to do - 
1. Define a handle threadHandle and define an array of handles h[20]...where each entry in the array has value threadHandle.

1. My code opens up 20 threads and once done, each thread has to signal the main thread and once all of them signal, the main thread has to log something to a log file.

I plan to do something like:

define threadHandle and the array of handles h[20} defined above.

Obnce the code opens 20 threads, do - `waitformultipleobjects(NULL,20,h,true,10000)`

Now the code will wait for the all the handles in the h array to be set before the wait returns. But since all the values of h are the same, the wait function returns an error. Is there a way to go around this? I basically need all the threads to signal back to the calling thread...defining 20 handlers for each of the 20 threads doesnt seem to be a good idea either.

Can I do something like this instead? -

define threadHandle and the array of handles h[20].
Maintain a variable count for the number of threads that signaled back to the main thread.

```
waitforsingleobject(threadHandle)
```

once this returns, increment count and if count < 20 repeat the above wait statement.
Keep doing it till count  = 20 and then log to file.
Of course, in between if any of the waits timesout, then we log a failure to the log file.

I am trying this out, but was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

TIA.
anand

Comment: Using the same event in multiple threads won't work. There's a good chance that you'll miss a few signaled events. Instead, use 20 unique  events as Jerry has mentioned. Have a EVT_BASE and init each event to EVT_BASE+1...+20. You can also improve your design to wrap the child thread and hide the initialization

Comment: All the values are the same?  WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Create 20 Event objects. Put their handles into `h`. Pass one to each thread you create. When the thread needs to signal the parent, it signals that event. The parent waits on the Event handles, and when they're all signaled, it writes to the log.

Answer (score 1):

Use one semaphore instead, (See CreateSemaphore() API, count initialized to 0), that all the threads signal.  WaitForSingleObject in a for loop, counting up to 20.  Much easier to set up, cannot miss any events and will work for any number of threads, (within reason).

Answer (score 0):

`Maintain a variable count for the number of threads`. Yes you can do that.

`nCount The number of object handles in the array pointed to by lpHandles. The maximum number of object handles is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS. This parameter cannot be zero.`

nCount is **not** specifying the array size but the number of handles to wait for. However, it shall not exceed the array size and both shall not exceed MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.

Hint: This is not limited to specific handles like thread handles. You can handle a mixture of various waitable handles this way. ([MSDN WaitForMultipleObjects function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

`But since all the values of h are the same...` **No**, they are not the same and the return value of `WaitForMultipleObjects` will vary accordingly (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + nCount).